# Eagle layout: how do I create an elongated hole under IC for isolation?

Tags: eaglecad, layout

I am kind of new to Eagle. I need to put a hole under an IC for isolation. An elongated oval to separate the sides of the chip. I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will probably have to discuss this with the board shop, to determine if they can mill a slot as you wish, and if so, how they want it documented.

Comment: While helpful, this doesn't discuss any methods to create an isolation gap in Eagle.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "cut out" layer to draw the shape you need. With the board shop I work with, at least, the minimum width of the cut-out is 100 mils.

The easiest way to do this is to draw a 100 mil wide line where you want your cut-out. You can either select the "cut out" layer before drawing the line or move it to that layer after it's drawn. It'll look something like this:

[image: example cutout]

[A full tutorial](http://docs.oshpark.com/submitting-orders/cutouts-and-slots/) (where this image is from) is available at OSH Park, who will also make the boards for you rather inexpensively.

Comment: Where is this corresponding "cut out" layer in Eagle? With isolation milling and pcb-gcode for example, the "milling" layer is usually used to cut the board by goind through the entire thickness.